# Arm doesn't want to merge with body

Tags: mesh

My arm that is a curve, doesn't want to merge with the body when I select both of them then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

At first, it works, I can move the whole body together with the arms
However, when I de-select it, and then click the body again, they don't go together anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you cannot merge the body and the arm together is that they are not the same type of object. The body is `Mesh` object, while the arm is a `Curve` object. You may only merge if both objects are the same type (with certain limitations, e.g. you cannot merge two Lamps, or two Cameras).

In order to merge the arm with the body you will need to first convert the arm to a mesh by selecting it and pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*.

After converting you can then merge the two mesh objects with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can Parent the curve to the Mesh with "Ctrl+P" and select "keep transform"

Then when you select and move the parent, the child will move with it, but they will be separate objects though.

Or you can put them in the same group
With "Ctrl+G" and move the originals to a different layer by selecting them and press "M" and choose the new layer.

Then go to a different layer, press "Shift+A", go down to group instance
and select the group you created.

You cant go into edit mode in the group instance, you will have to change the originals located on that other layer.